# React Native android release compilation AAPT2 error. PNG chunk is too large

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

After upgrading to gradle 3.3.0-alpha08 and wrapper 4.10-all distribution, I'm not able to complete compilation for release nor assembleRelease or generate signed APK.

I'm use react-native 0.56.1 (lastest)

My problem stands in android/app/src/main/res/drawable-{} set of folders, where all of my app`s png images are pushed to be assets of release app.
When Im compiling with that images there, android studio throws the error like this:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'. 
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource 
compilation failed
/Users/kindgeek/Foodilog-sprint-rc/android/app/src/main/res/drawable- 
mdpi/src_images_feed_image_default.png: error: failed reading from 
input: PNG chunk type 49444154 is too large: chunk length is 65524 but 
chunk starts at byte 393232/458752.
```

After I deleting images from drawable folders app compiles successfully but I'm not able to see any of asset images that is included in app. App just not viewing `<Image/>` resources inside anywhere.

Comment: Very weird compilation issue. Did not found anyone that had similar issue all over net. Firstly in my life. If someone will help me successfully go over this issue, I will mention his account or other way in my RN building and error overgoing guides

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

file `src_images_feed_image_default.png` has quite a few megabytes, at medium DPI.

the solution: properly scale & compress `PNG` / `WEBP` resource files, when adding them.

besides, using `alpha` stage build tools in combination with the term "urgent" is questionable.

Comment: What the maximum image sizes allowed in drawable/ ?

Comment: @JWJevaveh it is probably not the overall file-size - because when reading the error message and attempting to comprehend it, that one file might even be corrupt in general, due to excess size the last chunk, or the one chunk before the last; using stable build tools might also help.

Comment: Anyway, thank you @Martin . I wont to go over service terms about urgency. So my the best will be write in other words to highlight the real state of my thoughts.

Comment: @JWJevaveh the IDE almost always tells one what is wrong / what to do ...

Comment: So, am, I just reduced my big PNG's size to less and it started to work and compile as expected

Comment: Im gone little tired due to my first pre-release, and gone little out of mind

Comment: @JWJevaveh only noticed that, because with `alpha` versions, it is rather likely to waste time, compared to proven `stable` versions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179913/discussion-between-jw-jevaveh-and-martin-zeitler).

Answer (score 0):

Add `android.enableAapt2=false` to android/gradle.properties as a workaround

Comment: I need long term solution for this. Im confident about this workaround, but now need serious long term solution.
If answer was so simple for me, believe Im just did not to init this question at all))

Comment: well you did yell ASAP, thought you needed to get a release out